# How to create a character class of the following set

Tags: java, regex, character-class

```
+ - * / % < > = ! & ^ | ? :
```

I've tried:

```
[+-*/%<>=!&^|?:]
```

But I think some of them will need to be escaped. How can I tell which ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `-` as otherwise it'd be interpreted as a character range between `+` and `*`, which isn't valid:

```
[+\-*/%<>=!&^|?:]
```

The other metacharacters, as far as I know, are taken literally in a character class.

Comment: You can also move `-` to the beginning or the end of a character class and it'll be taken literally without escaping: `[-+*/%<>=!&^|?:]` But the order tends to be plus, minus, times, divide, not minus, plus, times, divide, so yeah...

Comment: The characters that have special meaning in a character class are `^-]\` , so I think ^ would need escaping as well...

Comment: @jball: `^` only has special meaning when it's the first character in a character class. Otherwise it's taken literally.

Comment: I wish I could +2 one foe the answer and other for the comments :)

Comment: @OscarRyz: You can always upvote the comments (if that wasn't you who just did) :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any masking, if you put the minus as first or last character into your group, because then it can't mean 'until' as in [a-z]. Similarly, the caret only means 'not in this group' if it is the first character of the group: [^a-z] := not a-z.
Quantifiers (+?*) don't make any sense in a group, so the characters, used to represent them, stand for themselves here. 
The other characters never mean something special in regexes.

Fast demo in scala:

```
for (c <- "-+*/%<>=!&^|?:") yield ("" + c).matches ("[-+*/%<>=!&^|?:]") 
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Boolean] =
  Vector(true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true)
```

Comment: Yeap, thank you. That's what BoltClock mentioned in one comment +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly enumerating the symbols to match, you can try using one of the character classes like \p{Punct} (matches US-ASCII punctuation) or \W matches non word characters !(A-Za-z0-9).

You'd use something like \p{Punct}* or \W* they may result in something a bit broader than your other search, but that might not be a bad thing....

Answer (score -1):

by reading the manual :-)? + is match at least one previous character, * means any number of characters, | is logical or, ^ defines a negation of a character.
You can also escape all of them to be sure!

**EDIT**

I see, i should have also read the manual first :-)